# How do I clear a warning for xcassets unassigned children?

Tags: ios, xcode7

Every time I build I receive two warnings:

```
<Project name>
    Assets.xcassets
        The launch image set "BrandAsset" has 2 unassigned children.

<Project name>
    Images.xcassets
        The launch image set "BrandAsset" has 2 unassigned children.
```

Not really sure what to do about this because I am assigning an existing storyboard for the `Launch Screen File`.

Under `Launch Screen Source`, I just see a button that says `Use Asset Catalog`.

How can I fix my build to clear these warnings?

Comment: Delete the unused "BrandAsset".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

just select unassigned items, then, remove:
[remove unassigned items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yptas.png)

Comment: @Greg This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Answer (score 0):

Assets.xcassets---> "Brand Assets", then right click--->"Remove selected Items"